# Каким образом можно посмотреть сколько ресурсов забирает пользователь в MS SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server

1. Как правильно снять значения счетчика(производительность) в СУБД MS SQL Server 2012?
2. Каким образом можно посмотреть сколько ресурсов забирает конкретный пользователь в MS SQL Server 2012?

Comment: Можно по старинке снять полный суточный или часовой трейс. Потом загрузить его в БД в проанализировать. Смотрите sp_trace_create, sp_trace_setevent, sp_trace_setfilter, sp_trace_setstatus. С помощью sp_trace_setevent можно настрить подходящие события, например 10 (RPC:Completed) и 12 (SQL:BatchCompleted). Для каждого события указать колонки - логин, cpu, duration или другие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для мониторинга состояния и различного рода показателей производительности в SqlServer существуют следующие средства.

**1. Динамические административные представления и функции** (*Dynamic
    Management Views and Functions*, [ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188754.aspx))

По первой части вопроса не совсем понятно, какие показатели вас интересуют. Посмотрите в `sys.dm_os_process_memory`, `sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats` или `sys.dm_os_performance_counters`, быть может найдёте интересующие.

По второй части вопроса можно сделать запрос к `sys.dm_exec_sessions`

```
select
    session_id,
    session_duration_sec = round(cast(getdate() - login_time as float) * 86400, 3),
    cpu_time_sec = round(cast(cpu_time as float) / 1000, 3),
    reads_Mb = round(cast(reads as float) / 128, 2),
    writes_Mb = round(cast(writes as float) / 128, 2),
    logical_reads_Mb = round(cast(logical_reads as float) / 128, 2)
from sys.dm_exec_sessions
where original_login_name = 'LoginName'
```

который вернёт данные по открытым в настоящий момент сессиям для заданного логина.

Хотя в некоторых случаях этой информации бывает достаточно, очевидно, однако, что таким способом нельзя получить информацию по завершившимся сессиям. Т.е. в некотором роде это "мгновенные" показатели.

Если интересуют не мгновенные показатели, а динамика, то отслеживать её можно делая polling. Такое решение, однако, может не подойти в случае, например, короткоживущих сессий. Тогда лучше воспользоваться средствами отслеживания событий.

**2. Трассировка** (*SQL Trace*, [ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh245121.aspx))

На сегодняшний день это средство является хоть и вполне рабочим, но устаревшим, поэтому я ограничусь лишь упоминанием о нём. Ему на смену пришли *расширенные события*.

**3. Расширенные события** (*Extended Events*, [ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb630282.aspx))

Этот инструмент, по сравнению с трассировкой, менее требователен к ресурсам (однако и им, при неумелом использовании, можно, как говорится, сервер "поставить на колени").

Данные о событиях можно собирать не только в файл, но и в простой *счётчик* или в *гистограмму* (что очень экономно с точки зрения расходования памяти), в *кольцевой буфер* (удобно для циклических событий). Можно настраивать автоматический запуск сессии расширенных событий при старте инстанса SqlServer.

По второй части вопроса можно, например, сделать отслеживание события `logout` (относится к пакету `sqlserver`), у которого есть поля

- duration
- cpu_time
- physical_reads
- logical_reads
- writes

содержащие накопленные за время сессии показатели, добавив фильтр `sqlserver.session_server_principal_name = N'LoginName'`.

Т.е., например:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [LoginName_resource_usage] ON SERVER
ADD EVENT sqlserver.logout (
    WHERE
        ([sqlserver].[session_server_principal_name] = N'LoginName')
    )
ADD TARGET package0.event_file (
    SET
        filename = N'd:\Temp\XE_Logs\LoginName_resource_usage.xel',
        max_file_size = 50,
        max_rollover_files = 0
    )
WITH (
    MAX_MEMORY = 4096 KB,
    EVENT_RETENTION_MODE = ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,
    MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY = 30 SECONDS,
    MAX_EVENT_SIZE = 0 KB,
    MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE = NONE,
    TRACK_CAUSALITY = OFF,
    STARTUP_STATE = OFF)
GO

ALTER EVENT SESSION [LoginName_resource_usage] ON SERVER  
    STATE = START
GO
```

После чего данные о событиях зачитываются (с помощью `sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file`) и анализируются (например, суммируются с разбивкой по интервалам времени и т.п.).